# How to pass object with known fields as props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am passing Person as props to a react component. I know that Persons is an array of Object where each Object has four field :

> 1) Name :(type string) 2) Surname :(type string) 3) Age :(type int) 4)
>   Address :(type string)

```
type Props = {
 Persons: Array<Object>,
}
```

Since I know the fields of object, passing using `Array<Object>,` is not a good idea(not descriptive). Is there some way I can pass this info as props ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to make two, separate interfaces to make it more readable. Also consider using `I` before the name, to show further code editors that it's an `interface`.

```
type IProps = {
  Persons: Array<IUser>,
}

type IUser = {
  name: string,
  surname: string,
  age: number,
  address: string,
}
```

Comment: Afaik that's not an interface, but a type? Using something like `PropsType` and `UserType` would be an adequate naming, [an interface in flow is something else](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#interface-syntax-a-classtoc-idtoc-interface-syntax-hreftoc-interface-syntaxa).

Comment: @nem035 Yeah, maybe it's not a native interface but the way of working is pretty the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, you can do just that:

```
type Props = {
 Persons: Array<{
   name: string,
   surname: string,
   age: number,
   address: string
 }>
}
```